# Need XSLT for multi-line item

Tags: xslt

I already tried a lot of things here on stack overflow but I still face the same problem.

Let me try to explain my issue and what I need to achieve. For this I have the following XML:

```
<authorizationGroups>               
<authorizationGroup>            <!-- can be multiple -->
    <name>OGroup 1</name>
    <application>               <!-- can be multiple -->
        <uid>646</uid>
        <applicationFunctions>  <!-- can be multiple -->
            <name>auth function 11</name>
            <name>auth function 12</name>
        </applicationFunctions> 
    </application>
    <role>5000682864</role>
    <role>5000685391</role>
</authorizationGroup>
<authorizationGroup>            <!-- can be multiple -->
    <name>OGroup 8</name>
    <application>               <!-- can be multiple -->
        <uid>646</uid>
        <applicationFunctions>  <!-- can be multiple -->
            <name>auth function 13</name>
            <name>auth function 14</name>
        </applicationFunctions> 
    </application>
    <role>5000683374</role>
    <role>5000685391</role>
</authorizationGroup>
```

I need to get out something like this:

```
<resource-types>
<resource-types>
        <resource-type>
                <name>OGroup 1</name>
                <actions>    
            auth function 11,
            auth function 12 
                </actions>
    </resource-type>
        <resource-type>
            <name>OGroup 8</name>
                <actions>   
            auth function 13,
            auth function 14  
                </actions>
        </resource-type>
</resource-types>
```

My problem is that when I use the XSLT I always end up with all the "auth functions xx" within one .

My current code snippet looks like this (there is obviously more than this part):

```
       <resource-types>
            <xsl:call-template name="resource_types"/>
        </resource-types>
<xsl:template name="resource_types">
    <resource-types>
        <xsl:for-each select="/authorizationGroups/authorizationGroup/name">
            <resource-type>
                <name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
                </name>
                <actions>

                    <xsl:for-each select="/authorizationGroups/authorizationGroup/application/applicationFunctions">
                        <xsl:value-of select=".//text()"/>
                        ,
                    </xsl:for-each>    
                </actions>
            </resource-type>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </resource-types>    
</xsl:template>
```

Now I receive all "auth functions xx" in one go. My understanding of XSLT is limited, so my main question is how can I limit the search for the  to the part of the XML document I am in.

I assumed that this was a very easy action, but after three days research on the net and stack overflow I haven't come up with an answer.

cu
Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is, I think, is that you are iterating over **name** elements, like so...

```
<xsl:for-each select="/authorizationGroups/authorizationGroup/name">
```

However, when you come to get the applicationFunctions within this **xsl:for-each**, you do this...

```
<xsl:for-each  
   select="/authorizationGroups/authorizationGroup/application/applicationFunctions">
```

Because of the forward slash at the start of the expression, this will get all **applicationFunctions** relative to the root of the document, and not the **authorizationGroup** you are currently in.

What you need to do is this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="../application/applicationFunctions">
```

The .. is to get the parent element, because you are currently positioned on the **name** element which is at the same level as the **application** element.

Actually, what would be slighty better would be it initially itereate over **authorizationGroup** to start with

```
<xsl:for-each select="/authorizationGroups/authorizationGroup">
```

And then iterate over the **applicationFunctions** like so

```
<xsl:for-each select="application/applicationFunctions">
```

Answer (score 0):

Either enclose the line break in `<xsl:text>` like (untested):

```
                    <xsl:for-each select="/authorizationGroups/authorizationGroup/application/applicationFunctions">
                        <xsl:value-of select=".//text()"/>
                        <xsl:text>,
</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:for-each>
```

or include it as an escape in `<xsl:value-of>` like (untested):

```
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat(.//text(), ',&#10;')"/>
```

Comment: Hi Tim! Thanks for your answer. Tried both but the problem is not the line break or the comma, but the fact that I receive all "auth functions xx" like this: <actions>   
      auth function 1 
      auth function 2 
    ,   
      auth function 15 
      auth function 16    ,</actions>                               I can deal with the comma later, but right now I receive too many auth functions (four instead of two)